# How do you center equations?

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment

I can't seem to center equations without causing some weird formatting problem.  The following results in the R being dropped:

```
\begin{center}
 E(R_{i,t})=E(\alpha_i)+E(\beta_{i,F_1 } F_{1,t})+E(\beta_{i,F_2 } F_{2,t})+\ldots+E(\beta_{i,F_m } F_{m,t})\linebreak
\bar{R}_{i,t}=a+\hat{\beta}_{i,F_1 } E(F_{1,t})+\hat{\beta}_{i,F_2 } E(F_{2,t})+\ldots+\hat{\beta}_{i,F_m } E(F_{m,t})\linebreak
\bar{R}_{i,t}=a+\gamma_1\hat{\beta}_{i,F_1 } +\gamma_2\hat{\beta}_{i,F_2 } F_{2,t}+\ldots+\gamma_m\hat{\beta}_{i,F_m }
\end{center}
```

Any ideas?  Is {center} the wrong thing to use?

Comment: Equations in displayed math environments are centered by default, See, e.g., `\[ 2+2=4 \]`. Are you using the `fleqn` option to your document class? Please edit your question to show a complete minimal document. Besides document class options, it's isn't clear what math environment the above occurs in (if any!) But, yes \begin{center} ... \end{center} is definitely the wrong thing to use.

Answer (score 135):

For a series of centered equations use the `gather` environment of amsmath:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
 E(R_{i,t})=E(\alpha_i)+E(\beta_{i,F_1 } F_{1,t})+E(\beta_{i,F_2 } F_{2,t})+
    \ldots+E(\beta_{i,F_m } F_{m,t})\\
\bar{R}_{i,t}=a+\hat{\beta}_{i,F_1 } E(F_{1,t})+\hat{\beta}_{i,F_2 } E(F_{2,t})+
    \ldots+\hat{\beta}_{i,F_m } E(F_{m,t})\\
 \bar{R}_{i,t}=a+\gamma_1\hat{\beta}_{i,F_1 } +\gamma_2\hat{\beta}_{i,F_2 } F_{2,t}+
    \ldots+\gamma_m\hat{\beta}_{i,F_m }
\end{gather*} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of centering you may consider to align all equations at the equal sign and center the whole multiline environment. For this, use the `align` or `align*` environment, see the [amsmath user's guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) (or type *texdoc amsldoc* at the command prompt).

In any case, use [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). That package provides many kinds of multiline diplayed formula environments.

Comment: how do I have single equation number exactly in the middle? I don't want to use `\nonumber'

Comment: @JohnSmith Use an `equation` environment, within that use an `aligned` or `split` environment.

Comment: I tried that before but with `aligned` or `split` within `equation` environment the equations are aligned to the right. I want centering+single equation number. Any ideas?

Comment: @JohnSmith With `aligned` or `split` use `&` for marking an alignment position (relation symbol). For centering, use `gathered` within `equation`.

Comment: how will this work when I have sub equations within each equation?

Comment: Gathered and upvoted ;)

Comment: Is it possible to center a single equation within an `align*` (i.e., to ignore the alignment for the line in question)?

Answer (score 61):

The `center` environment is for text, not math. What you want here is (this also lines up the equals signs):

```
\begin{align*}
  E(R_{i,t})    &= E(\alpha_i)+E(\beta_{i,F_1 } F_{1,t})+E(\beta_{i,F_2 } F_{2,t})+\ldots+E(\beta_{i,F_m } F_{m,t}) \\
  \bar{R}_{i,t} &= a+\hat{\beta}_{i,F_1 } E(F_{1,t})+\hat{\beta}_{i,F_2 } E(F_{2,t})+\ldots+\hat{\beta}_{i,F_m } E(F_{m,t}) \\
  \bar{R}_{i,t} &= a+\gamma_1\hat{\beta}_{i,F_1 } +\gamma_2\hat{\beta}_{i,F_2 } F_{2,t}+\ldots+\gamma_m\hat{\beta}_{i,F_m }
\end{align*}
```

You need the `amsmath` package for `align*`, so make sure you have the line `\usepackage{amsmath}` in your preamble (before `\begin{document}`).

Comment: Great Sophie! I didn't consider this point of view till I see this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to center math is the use of backslash and square brakets

`\[ k* {{n}\choose{k}} = n*{{n-1}\choose{k-1}}\]`

Comment: The question doesn't deal with a single equation, but with multiple ones.

Comment: Yes, but anyway it rest the most simple way to do it, just repeating 
 backslash and square brakets each line that also give the right space to formula and avoid problems f.ex. in Sum, Int... where the operator can be, viceversa, reduced in height. Thanks for the downvote, it is a pleasure to be here.

Comment: No, the vertical spacing between consecutive `\[...\]` displays is wrong.

Comment: Pls can you explain it better so we can all can understand ? I use it from long time. Thanks