# Extra Space between equation and line above that

Tags: equations

How the distance between first line and equation and last line and equation is different.
How to remove the extra space.

[image]

I am using this code

```
 According to given assumption that n is a power of 2 or $n=2^k$
    \begin{center}
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:solve}
     2T(n/2) + 1     
    \end{equation}
    \end{center}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for custom headers
\usepackage{lastpage} % Required to determine the last page for the footer
\usepackage{extramarks} % Required for headers and footers
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color} % Required for custom colors
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required to insert images
\usepackage{listings} % Required for insertion of code
\usepackage{courier} % Required for the courier font
\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template
\usepackage{mathtools}          %loads amsmath as well
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Floor\lfloor\rfloor
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Ceil\lceil\rceil

% Margins
\topmargin=-0.45in
\evensidemargin=0in
\oddsidemargin=0in
\textwidth=6.5in
\textheight=9.0in
\headsep=0.25in

\linespread{1.1} % Line spacing
\begin{document}
\begin{section}
According to given assumption that n is a power of 2 or $n=2^k$

\section{equation} 
 2T(n/2) + 1     
\end{equation}

Using Master Theorem where a=2, b=2, d=0;


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001), not just a code snippet.

Comment: what is compatible MWE ?

Comment: Please follow the link to learn what an MWE is.

Comment: Incidentally, where did you "learn" to encase an `equation` environment inside a `center` environment? (Remove the `center` environment code and the excess vertical space will disappear.)

Comment: Still some extra space is there i have added MWE

Comment: And why using center element gives extra space.

Comment: You still have some extra space, because you now have a blank line (which starts a new paragraph) before `\begin{equation}`. Please study any introductory LaTeX tutorial to learn some of the basics of TeX and LaTeX -- including what *not* to do, such as (a) encasing an `equation` environment in a `center` environment, (b) leaving a blank line above a `\begin{equation}` statement, or (c) using nonexistent instructions such as `\begin{section}` and `\end{section`.

Comment: Thanks man just started with that all however section thing actually i was using my own definition so included in braces but forget to add definition in beginning for MWE.

Comment: One reason for requesting a *compilable* MWE rather than some code snippets is that it becomes immediately evident that things such as `\section{equation} ... `\end{equation}` cannot possibly work. Before posting code revisions, please do check if the revised code even compiles.

Comment: The supplied MWE clearly does not produce the image shown.

Comment: unrelated to the vertical space issues but `where a=2, b=2, d=0;` should be `where $a=2$, $b=2$, $d=0$;`

Answer (score 5):

First of all, your MWE doesn't work because you wrote `\section{equation}` ... `\end{equation}`. Latex does not recognise these tags to be paired, so change the first one to `\begin{equation}`.

Delete the `\begin{section}` and `\end{section}` tags, they serve no purpose. If you want to start a chapter in your document (for the `article` class), then write `\section{Title here}`.

As it has also been suggested to you in the comments, leaving a blank line produces a wider vertical space. So for the following code:

```
According to given assumption that $n$ is a power of $2$ or $n=2^k$

\begin{equation} 
 2T(n/2) + 1     
\end{equation}

According to given assumption that $n$ is a power of $2$ or $n=2^k$
\begin{equation} 
 2T(n/2) + 1     
\end{equation}
```

You get this result. The first example shows more distance than the second one (although not that evident, it's still present).

[image]

Your equation is already centered, so you don't need a `center` environment, which is what caused the huge space in your case. Also, it's for text anyway, not math, so you have no reason to be using it in this instance. For centering *multiple* equations, see this question: [How do you center equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8423/4778)